# Update a column in one spreadsheet by matching a key column in a second spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare, row

I have two excel files which have the same unique key and would like to update data from one file to another. To be more specific: I have FileA that has the unique key on Column B and FileB that has the unique key on Column B as well. I would like to update FileA:ColumnK from FileB:ColumnD **BUT** the records are not in the same order!

That means that row 14 on FileA is row 525 on FileB. So my solution would be on cell K14=FileB:D525...

I found a formula to check for duplicates. It works, but I want to pull data from one file to another from different rows!

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Open the second file, copy it into another sheet into the first file and use `VLOOKUP`

Comment: A unique key means either an `INDEX(MATCH())` pair or `VLOOKUP` with *FALSE* as the optional *range_lookup* parameter. see [VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010069835.aspx)

Comment: Here is a good example: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/08/23/excel-vlookup-from-another-workbook/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, as [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) noted, you should use an `INDEX(MATCH())` pair or `VLOOKUP()` function.

That is what's your `VLOOKUP()` function should look like (assuming it's entered in cell D2 of your FileA):

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,[FileB.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$2:$D$10,3,0)
```

B2:D10 range in the second argument should be expanded to include all of the data in FileB. Dollar signs make the reference absolute, so it doesn't change when you copy that formula down to all the cells in FileA's column D.

As for `INDEX(MATCH())` pair, this is an example:

```
=INDEX([FileB.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$2:$D$10,MATCH(B2,[FileB.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10,0),3)
```

Syntax is a bit complex, but this function is generally faster than `VLOOKUP()`. Ranges B2:D10 and B2:B10 in this example should also be expanded to include all the real data.

Either way, it will be useful to read internal Excel help on these functions to know what are their arguments at least.